# How to model cycloids with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, graph

For an extra credit assignment, my PreCalc teacher said I could make a program that models cycloids. I haven't done much work with Javascript, but I understand it and could create something with it if I knew the overall organization of how this could be made.

I want to make something that [looks like this Gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aCycloid_f.gif), but in javascript that allows one to edit the equation and have the animation change.

For those who don't know - [This is the cartesian equation for a cycloid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HolH4.png)

Comment: This should be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

Comment: Tell me if this sounds decent. I think it can be done if I make a circle. Then the circle will move across the screen and turn at the same time. On the outer perimeter of the circle I will place a point. Then using the library I found, I think I can make a dot every interval at the location of the point. Can Canvas draw the dot based on the location of the point on the circle? How would I track the location of the point on the circle?

Comment: You don't *need* a circle to draw it. The circle is just a visualization tool. For every delta-x, draw a circle, a point with a y-coordinate according to your function, and connect the previous point's location to the current one with a line. Truthfully, this is a ton of work for a bit of extra credit.

Comment: Maybe I'll just make a static graph without the animation...